# Derivation of the current density for the free electron gas

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics

I have a few doubts about the study of the free electron gas model:

1. We know that the current density expression may be calculated as follows

**J**(**r**,t)=$\frac{\hbar}{2mi}(\psi^{*}\nabla\psi -\psi\nabla\psi^{*})$,

where $m$ is the mass of the particle, $t$ is the time, and $\psi^{*}$ the complex conjugate of the wave function.

If the wave function of the free electron gas model is

$\psi(\textbf{r})=\psi_{o}exp[i\textbf{k} .\textbf{r}]$,

where **k** is the wave-vector, **r** is the position vector, and $\psi_{o}$ is the wave's amplitude.

How could I calculate **J**(**r**,t) from $\psi(\textbf{r})$?

2. For a real wave function, what would be the result for **J**(**r**,t)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You do not say what your "doubts" are.

If $\Psi(x)= \sqrt \rho e^{ikx}$ with $\rho=|\psi|$ a real number, you just plug into your formula for $J$ to get
$$
J=\rho \hbar \frac k m.
$$
Note that the derivatoves of $\rho$ cancel between the two terms in $J$.
As $p= \hbar k$ is the momentum $mv$, this is
$$
J= \rho v
$$
as expected.  If $\psi$ is real then $J=0$ everywhere.

What part of this do you find puzzling?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I have studied these concepts some years ago,  and  I was not so sure about how to proceed

Comment: In your answer, you have restricted your solution to the one-dimensional case. What would be the result in three dimensions?

Comment: Just the same:If $\psi({\bf x},t)= \sqrt \rho e^{i\theta({\bf x},t)}$ we have   ${\bf J}= \rho {\bf v}$ with ${\bf v}= \nabla \theta/m$.

Comment: I see it. However, what is $\theta$ if my wave function is $\psi(\textbf{r})=\psi_{o}exp(i\textbf{k}\cdot\textbf{r})$?

Comment: $\theta= {\bf k}\cdot {\bf r}$.